# javascript. Show embeded pdf on click

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, embed

When I click the link "show pdf" I want to display the embeded pdf. However there must be something wrong. The pdf will now load. Some help?

Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benjones337/7jkmvLL9/2/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("showPDF").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("thePDF").style.visibility = "visible";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div>
  <object data="http://www.elml.org/website/en/download/gitta_databases.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <embed id="thePDF" src="http://www.elml.org/website/en/download/gitta_databases.pdf" width="700" height="575" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
    <p><a id="showPDF">Show PDF</a></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start. You can not have nested paragraph tags.

Comment: You already asked this question 30 minutes ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547477/will-not-show-embeded-pdf#comment47246515_29547477)...

Comment: Updated code and deleted other post

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using onload event in jsfiddle as this event already happened when the page is "loaded".
2. Hide the object itself (I moved your id to the parent element) as the embed element is not affected with your style.

jsfiddle.net/7jkmvLL9/6/

Comment: Thanks. Will the pdf just not load in jfiddle ? I'll try it directly in my browser later.

Comment: I've tried this one with firefox and is working jsfiddle.net/7jkmvLL9/6/